# Optimising a four-state data structure

Tags: python

I am manipulating *many* instances of the same data structure which can have one of four states. Currently I implement the states using `True`/`False` pairs:

```
(True, True)
(True, False)
(False, True)
(False, False)
```

With those data-structures I repeatedly apply two functions `f`, `g` where

```
g((True, True)) = (True, False)
g((True, False)) = (True, True)
g((False, True)) = (False, False)
g((False, False)) = (False, True)
```

and

```
f((True, True)) = (False, False)
f((True, False)) = (False, True)
f((False, True)) = (True, False)
f((False, False)) = (True, True)
```

Can I improve upon this data structure for those two functions? (I want to optimise for speed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an integer in the range of 0..3 and implement the state transitions with bit arithmetic (`g` xors with 1; `f` xors with 3).

Answer (score 1):

The code you use to manipulate these states will have a much larger impact on performance than how you store the state.  And how you need to manipulate it will determine the best way to store it.  Without knowing more about the algorithms involved, it's impossible to comment on the data representation.

Is the state naturally represented as two booleans, or is it four distinct states?

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question with the two operations I have on my data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the states using a symbol representation of each state:

```
(True, True)    == 3 decimal or 11 binary
(True, False)   == 2 decimal or 10 binary
(False, True)   == 1 decimal or 01 binary
(False, False)  == 0 decimal or 00 binary
```

Here are functions f and g

```
g((True, True)) = (True, False)
is the same as 
g(3) == 2 decimal
or 
XOR with 01 binary operation

g((True, False)) = (True, True)
is the same as 
g(2) == 3
or 
XOR with 01 binary operation

g((False, True)) = (False, False)
is the same as 
g(1) == 0
or 
XOR with 01 binary operation

g((False, False)) = (False, True)
is the same as 
g(0) == 1
or 
XOR with 01 binary operation
```

and

```
f((True, True)) = (False, False)
is the same as 
f(3) = 0
or 
XOR with 11 binary operation

f((True, False)) = (False, True)
is the same as 
f(2) = 1
or 
XOR with 11 binary operation

f((False, True)) = (True, False)
is the same as 
f(1) = 2
or 
XOR with 11 binary operation

f((False, False)) = (True, True)
is the same as 
f(0) = 3
or 
XOR with 11 binary operation
```

That's it!
Hope I've answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a quadtree and a quadkey to store the states. The query would be more efficient when you need a fast lookup and when you need to find subtrees. You can look further into quadtrees and use a monster curve. A monster curve completley fills a space but it's still a curve. Placing your states along that curve you can sort them in 2 dimension reducing it to 1 dimension. It's like having a hierarchcal cluster. A most famous monster curve is the hilbert curve.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simplest thing to do would be not to use functions, but to build two dictionaries f and g with keys given by the arguments and values given by the outcomes.

That will be slower than mapping the pairs to 0...3 and making two arrays f and g (arrays will be faster than lists for lookups, and numpy arrays perhaps even faster), or even two functions, since in fact `f(x)= 3-x` (or bitwise not: `~x`) and `g(x)=x^1` (^ is XOR), which might be fastest.